# Does the line" Tears of disbelief sting my eyes" make sense?

Tags: word-choice

Can I use the words - "Tears of disbelief sting my eyes" to express the fact that I am very sad and shocked?

Comment: In the same way that "Colorless green dreams sleep furiously" makes sense.

Comment: People don't typically "cry in disbelief"; you may be shocked and sorrowful, and unable to believe what you just heard, but it is the shock or sorrow that makes you cry, not the disbelief.  (Also, strictly speaking, if you *really* didn't believe, you wouldn't be crying at all.)  Short answer: yes, it makes sense, but only when provided with sufficient context, to the extent that I recommend you rephrase the sentence altogether.

Comment: 1) Disbelief usually doesn't result in tears (despair or pain or excessive hilarity might). 2) Tears usually don't sting your eye, tears are more likely the result of something stinging your eyes. Maybe disbelief is sting your eyes, and then they tear up. My diagnosis: you must be allergic to disbelief.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about creative writing advice - IMHO, *highly* "creative".

Comment: I like this question, and I don't want to see it closed.  Just my 2 cents (or 2 pence).

Comment: @Mitch, I can see tears of disbelief when something that one has earnestly hoped for, and expected, suddenly fails to occur.  I once experienced this at the outcome of an election to public office, and believe me when I freely admit that I shed tears of disbelief.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Poetic license, or more accurately, "[artistic license](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artistic_license)" must be considered here.  Robusto's comment is perfectly appropriate, but there is no doubt in my mind that in some context "colorless green dreams sleep furiously" might actually make sense!  In the description of a drug-induced state, for example.

And you cannot tell me that the famous poem "Jabberwocky" doesn't contain a hefty helping of artistic license!

```
'Twas brillig, and the slithy toves 
Did gyre and gimble in the wabe;
All mimsy were the borogoves, 
And the mome raths outgrabe.
```

Does any part of this make ANY kind of sense?  Of course not, but that is the point.

License, my friends, means that something is permitted, IF you can get the reader to swallow it.

And "Tears of disbelief sting my eyes" is perfectly capable getting buyoff from readers.

Comment: oh! +1 for quoting from my favorite Sci-fi story! :-)

Comment: @KristinaLopez, I didn't think I quoted from any sci-fi story.  Or where was *Jabberwocky* quoted in such a story?

Comment: Actually, the Scifi story, *"Mimsey Were the Borogoves"*, by Lewis Padgett, references the poem and is woven into the story...http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mimsy_Were_the_Borogoves

Comment: @Cyberherbalist - I am planning to use it in a poem. It would be quite embarrassing if the readers find it senseless :P

Comment: @TheLostMind: I am not a poet, nor do I play one on TV, but my understanding is that sometimes poetry gets its impact by using unusual images. I did not find the phrasing at all senseless, FWIW.

Comment: @KristinaLopez: *Through the Looking Glass* is sci-fi?

Comment: @Robusto, see my comment - the Lewis Padgett story that references the Jabberwocky poem, is science fiction.

Comment: @Cyberherbalist - last page or 2nd-to-last page of the story.

Comment: Ah, I didn't read the whole comment chain.